# Angular - Update model without using $parsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I know that I can have the model be different than the view value by using $parsers.

But what if I want to have the model change, without using $parsers?

For example:

**html**

```
<input tel-input ng-model="data.phone">
{{data.phone}}
```

**js**

```
.directive('telInput', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('paste', function() {
        scope.ngModel = 'special model value after pasting';
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The problem with this is that when `scope.ngModel = 'pasting not allowed` occurs, it changes the value in the input.

With $parsers, it changes the value in the model, but the view value remains the same.

There isn't any $setModelValue method, which seems like it would serve this purpose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.directive('telInput', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
       elem.on('paste', function() {
         ngModel.$setViewValue('special model value after pasting');
         ngModel.$render();
       });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: still changes the value in the input :/

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: "The problem with this is that when scope.ngModel = 'pasting not allowed occurs, it changes the value in the input."

Comment: @TaylorMac: Do you actually want values in the view and model to be different? So that view displays something different from the model?